# Speed up grep and awk with gnu-parallel

Tags: bash, awk, grep, gnu-parallel

I am looking to speed up two lines of grep and awk code with the great gnu-parallel tool, but using the simple syntax it breaks down or loops to infinity. Help is greatly appreciated!

Normal code:

```
for FILENAME in `cat FileList.tmp`
do
  echo "Bearbeite $FILENAME ..."
  FILE_BASENAME=`echo ${FILENAME##*/}`
  grep -v "^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$" ${FILENAME} > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp
  awk '{ if (gsub("t=|r=|i=|d=|ip=|ua=|uc=|um=|ud=|pc=|la=|lo=|do=|dm=|c=","")) print; else print}' \
      ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}
  rm -f ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp
done
```

Parallel try:

```
[...]  
parallel -j100 --pipe grep -v "^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$" | awk '{s = s + $1} END {print s, s/NR}' ${FILENAME} > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp  
awk '{ if (gsub("t=|r=|i=|d=|ip=|ua=|uc=|um=|ud=|pc=|la=|lo=|do=|dm=|c=","")) print; else print}' \
      ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}
 [...]
```

My thoughts are that I just piped the parallel commands the wrong way...

Comment: I think that the best way of speeding this up will be to avoid writing to an intermediate file and to combine your grep and awk commands into a single awk command.

Comment: Moreover, if your bottleneck is I/O bound, adding parallelism will not make it faster at all (unless you can parallelize the I/O specifically, such as by breaking up the input into smaller chunks, and manipulating each in a separate process; but that is hardly worth the effort here unless you do this often and/or on a massive scale).

Comment: While that used to be true, it no longer is: I have used a RAID that was 6 times faster if I ran 10 jobs in parallel. The RAID was slower if I ran fewer or more jobs in parallel. With SSD disks it is even less true. So the only advice that really still holds is: measure which works better for you.

Answer (score 2):

Some thinkings:

```
while IFS= read -r FILENAME
do
   echo "Bearbeite $FILENAME ..."
   FILE_BASENAME=${FILENAME##*/} # no need to echo
   grep -v "^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$" ${FILENAME} > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp
   awk '{ if (gsub("t=|r=|i=|d=|ip=|ua=|uc=|um=|ud=|pc=|la=|lo=|do=|dm=|c=","")) print; else print}' \
    ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}
   rm -f ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp
done < FileList.tmp
```

- use `while read ... done < file` instead of `cat` blabla.
- do not use `echo ${FILENAME##*/}` to assign the variable, just do `FILE_BASENAME=${FILENAME##*/}`.
- explain what you want to accomplish with the `grep/awk` pair, because it can probably be improved. For example the following expression does not make much sense.

  ```
  awk '{if (gsub("t=|...|c=","")) print; else print}' ...
  ```

You want to perform either of these: replace and then print the line, or print the original line if no replacement was done. This you can do by directly saying `gsub(); print`, because `gsub()` updates the value of `$0` (the line) in case it matches:

```
awk '{gsub("t=|...|c=",""); print}' ...
```

Comment: The `grep` command should delete lines that are empty, keep only the files that match the regex `^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$`.
`awk` should substitute the t=|r= blabla with an empty character ""
after the commands the modifications should be put in a new file

Answer (score 1):

As fedorqui has already made some points on the structure of your loop, I will focus on combining the grep and awk parts:

```
awk '!(/^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$/) {
     gsub(/(t|r|i|d|ip|ua|uc|um|ud|pc|la|lo|do|dm|c)=/,""); print }' input > output
```

When the pattern doesn't match (same as `grep -v`), perform the substitution and print the result. Other lines will not be printed.

In awk, `gsub` modifies the target (the whole record, `$0`, by default) and returns the number of substitutions made. I have removed the conditional code as it seems that you want to print the record, whether any substitutions were made or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a script that does the job for a single file, it is usually trivially simple to convert it to GNU Parallel:

```
bearbeite() {
  FILENAME=$1
  echo "Bearbeite $FILENAME ..."
  FILE_BASENAME=`echo ${FILENAME##*/}`
  grep -v "^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$" ${FILENAME} > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp
  awk '{ if (gsub("t=|r=|i=|d=|ip=|ua=|uc=|um=|ud=|pc=|la=|lo=|do=|dm=|c=","")) print; else print}' \
    ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}
  rm -f ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}.tmp
}
export -f bearbeite
parallel bearbeite :::: FileList.tmp
# or:
cat FileList.tmp | parallel bearbeite
```

To avoid the temporary file this ought to work:

```
bearbeite() {
  FILENAME=$1
  echo "Bearbeite $FILENAME ..."
  FILE_BASENAME=`echo ${FILENAME##*/}`
  grep -v "^t=[0-9]*.[0-9]*\&\-$" ${FILENAME} |
  awk '{ if (gsub("t=|r=|i=|d=|ip=|ua=|uc=|um=|ud=|pc=|la=|lo=|do=|dm=|c=","")) print; else print}' > ${INPUT}/cleaned/${FILE_BASENAME}
}
```